# ValidationError: Progress Plugin Invalid Options when compiling vue project

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli-3

I am getting a nugging error message when trying to complile my vue project. This is the error message
ValidationError: Progress Plugin Invalid Options

```
    options should NOT have additional properties
    options should NOT have additional properties
    options should NOT have additional properties
    options should pass "instanceof" keyword validation
    options should match exactly one schema in oneOf
```

ValidationError: Progress Plugin Invalid Options

options should NOT have additional properties
options should NOT have additional properties
options should NOT have additional properties
options should pass "instanceof" keyword validation
options should match exactly one schema in oneOf

```
at validateOptions (E:\Skyline\work\peach-hq__vue\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\schema-utils\src\validateOptions.js:32:11)
at new ProgressPlugin (E:\Skyline\work\peach-hq__vue\node_modules\webpack\lib\ProgressPlugin.js:62:3)
at new Progress (E:\Skyline\work\peach-hq__vue\node_modules\progress-webpack-plugin\index.js:25:21)
at new progressPlugin (E:\Skyline\work\peach-hq__vue\node_modules\progress-webpack-plugin\index.js:127:10)
at E:\Skyline\work\peach-hq__vue\node_modules\webpack-chain\src\Plugin.js:14:18
at module.exports.toConfig (E:\Skyline\work\peach-hq__vue\node_modules\webpack-chain\src\Plugin.js:78:22)
at E:\Skyline\work\peach-hq__vue\node_modules\webpack-chain\src\Config.js:129:63
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at module.exports.toConfig (E:\Skyline\work\peach-hq__vue\node_modules\webpack-chain\src\Config.js:129:40)
at Service.resolveWebpackConfig (E:\Skyline\work\peach-hq__vue\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:277:34)
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "Hehe",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "watch": "npx tailwindcss -i ./src/assets/tailwind.css -o ./src/assets/styles.css --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^2.0.8",
    "@sentry/vue": "^7.48.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "compass-sass-mixins": "^0.12.7",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "echarts": "^5.4.1",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "keycloak-js": "^18.0.0",
    "sass": "~1.32.13",
    "vue": "^2.7.14",
    "vue-echarts": "^6.5.4",
    "vue-html-to-paper": "^1.4.4",
    "vue-js-modal": "^2.0.1",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vue-sweetalert2": "^5.0.5",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.24.3",
    "vuejs-logger": "^1.5.5",
    "vuex": "^3.4.0",
    "vuex-persist": "^3.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/composition-api": "^1.7.1",
    "cache-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^8.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.18",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "raw-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.2.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8",
    "vue-cli-plugin-tailwind": "~3.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.14"
  }
}
```

And this is part of that progressplugin caught in the error class ProgressPlugin {

````
     * @param {ProgressPluginArgument} options options
     */
    constructor(options) {
        if (typeof options === "function") {
            options = {
                handler: options
            };
        }

        options = options || {};
        validateOptions(schema, options, "Progress Plugin");
        options = Object.assign({}, ProgressPlugin.defaultOptions, options);

        this.profile = options.profile;
        this.handler = options.handler;
        this.modulesCount = options.modulesCount;
        this.showEntries = options.entries;
        this.showModules = options.modules;
        this.showActiveModules = options.activeModules;
    }```
What could be causing this?
````